# Recommended jslint config?

Tags: javascript, jslint

[JSlint](http://www.jslint.com/) allows setting options in a comment block at the beginning of your script and some of them could help make it less annoying to use. I am hoping for some more productivity.

I picked these to start with:

```
/*jslint devel: true, browser: true, unparam: true, debug: false, es5: true, white: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */
```

What are the established defaults?

[I am really trying to make it NOT subjective, but yeah, I want to know what works for you]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically this works for me, disabled all annoying stuff.

```
/*jslint white: true, browser: true, devel: true, windows: true, forin: true, vars: true, nomen: true, plusplus: true, bitwise: true, regexp: true, sloppy: true, indent: 4, maxerr: 50 */
```

Comment: Ok, that's a lot :) Care to describe why you needed some of them? I'm not sure why there's the forin set to true

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "less annoying for use"? Not using JSLint is the least annoying.

The defaults are already set by default in JSLint; thus, the defaults are "no overrides". However, in some cases you have to override the defaults; for you, that would probably be `browser: true` (to allow javascript to interact with browser) and `devel: true` (if you want to use `alert`, `console.log` etc; btw, consider using browser's integrated debugger instead).

Comment: I strongly disagree here. JSLint enforces code formatting which simply is what Douglas Crockford prefers (I talked to him on a conference last year and he himself said it is good to turn off some features for everyday work). Not being able to use `var` inside `for` loop is also not the best of ideas.

Comment: <i>Not being able to use var inside for loop is also not the best of ideas</i> - it is done to prevent you from mistakes related to variables in JS being declared in a function scope, not in for loop scope. Anyway, do you have any problems with the enforced code formatting?

Comment: Having spent years writing code in one convention I find myself unwilling to follow another if I gain nothing. I am aware of the reasons behing conventions in JSLint and I know it attempts to increase understandability, but the rules I evolved around using variables in for loops increase understandability further. I don't understand why should we discuss whether I have a problem or not here on SO. Answer to such a question is not useful to anyone.

Comment: things like vars: true being even there is a case of FML 

for some godforsaken reason its not disabling in my code base

Comment: @penartur I just added jslint to my vim and it is annoying.  The most annoying thing so far is that it flags this beautiful line `if (!url) url = window.location.href;`

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Komodo Edit](http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/) (open source editor) and use its configuration tool for JsLint or JsHint, here is how for JsLint:

[image]

which gives you the config string

[image]